# Recovering an ext4 partition

Tags: linux, ext4, disk, fsck

I have an external drive with an ext4 partition `/dev/sda1` I use for my local borg backups.

It is simply plugged in via usb port, and, mounted with an `fstab` generated systemd automount entry. I ran a backup yesterday in the evening without any errors, and this morning, I plugged it in, it was not recognized anymore. The drive would show up with lsblk, but no partition under it.

I ran `sudo fsck -R -C -V -t ext4 /dev/sda1` and got the following output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.39.2
[/usr/bin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.ext4 -C0 /dev/sda1 
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda1
Could this be a zero-length partition?
/dev/sda1: status 8, rss 3232, real 0.002321, user 0.001784, sys 0.000000
```

I have no idea how to interpret that. I only can see the exit code status 8 the man page describes as an 'operational error'.

BEGIN EDIT

Output for `sudo parted /dev/sda print`

```
Error: Invalid partition table on /dev/sda -- wrong signature 0.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: SABRENT  (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      8225kB  1000GB  1000GB  extended               lba
```

Output of `sudo dmesg` right after plugging the drive in

```
[16265.871467] usb 2-6.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[16265.889474] usb 2-6.4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561, bcdDevice= 2.04
[16265.889486] usb 2-6.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16265.889491] usb 2-6.4: Product: SABRENT
[16265.889495] usb 2-6.4: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[16265.889499] usb 2-6.4: SerialNumber: DB9876543214E
[16265.899660] scsi host4: uas
[16265.900160] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT                   0204 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[16268.706521] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[16268.706530] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[16268.706759] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[16268.706768] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[16268.707113] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[16268.707265] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[16268.707270] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
[16268.724287]  sda: sda1 < >
[16268.724396] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[16296.811964] usb 2-6.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[16340.865861]  sda: sda1 < >
```

Following telecoM advice, I ran `sudo losetup --sector-size 4096 -P -f /dev/sdx`. I have a loop1p1 device/partition now.

```
❯ sudo parted /dev/loop1p1 print
Error: /dev/loop1p1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Unknown (unknown)                                                  
Disk /dev/loop1p1: 4096B
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

❯ sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/loop1p1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/loop1p1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

END EDIT

Should I give up on trying to recover this partition ? (I have redundant backups, it is not a catastrophe for me, I just want to learn in anticipation for the day it might be one).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your first assumption is interesting because the drive is a SATA disk for which I bought a case recently (as shown in my edit, the manufacturer is sabrent). Maybe I went too cheap with that enclosing. Anyway I tried getting the sata drive out and back in, with no effects. I added the info you requested, by could not find `/var/log/kern.log`. I am on manjaro kde if that helps. thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: You are right, I did not think of looking for it this way. I am not going to insist then, I am going to get a new case and research the manufacturer more carefully this time. I would mark your first comment as an answer and 'close' this question, but I am not sure how to proceed. Should I answer my own question ?

Comment: Note `Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B`. If the case originally used native 4KiB sectors, you might need `losetup --sector-size 4096 -P -f /dev/sda` and then access the whole disk via `/dev/loopN` and its partitions via `/dev/loopNpM` (where `N` is the first free loop device number and M is a partition number).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Don't you think this would have been an issue right off the bat instead of happening out of the blue after a couple of weeks of normal operations with hourly backups ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the more usual way, but whenever you see a disk that has apparently lost its partition table and has the capability to use the 4KiB sector size in addition to the classic 512 byte sectors, it does not take all that long to check the other possible sector size too... just to be sure. Since the disk seems to have lost its partitions, something has already failed: checking for the possibility that the failure is in sector size auto-detection is quick and easy to do, so it's worth doing in my opinion.

Comment: I will try to read more on loop devices tonight, I am not familiar with this concept. The `losetup` command you recommended did not throw an error. I do have a /dev/loop0p1 listed now. and the device still appears under /dev/sda. As I do not really know what to do with it, I tried the `parted` cmd from my original post, logical/physical sectors do match at 4096b now, bu I got error unrecognised disk label, model unknown, Partition Table unknown. I tried opening KDE partition manager, and the device appears under /dev/loop, and /dev/sda, only the former displays sizes 10x bigger than it is.

Comment: Looks like the KDE partition manager does not yet support 4096b block size, and so assumes all blocks are 512 bytes - that works out to exactly 8x size difference. You could try running a `fsck` on `/dev/loop0p1`, or `parted /dev/loop0` to see if it sees a valid partition table or not. If those won't work any better than before, then my guess was wrong.

Comment: You are most definitely right about the block size discrepancy in KDE partition manager, that evaded me... My previous comment was not clear because I was lacking space to share the outputs with you so I decided to edit my original question again since `fsck` does give a different output than before.

Comment: Editing the original question **is exactly the right way** to add more information to a question on StackExchange. But although the `fsck` response is *different*, it is unfortunately not any *better*; in fact, it looks like the `fsck` on `sda1` got slightly further before giving up. I would agree with @roaima's estimation at this point: the Sabrent case is probably failing. (BTW, when using a loop device, you should use `parted /dev/loop0`: directing `parted` to the `loop0p1` partition device will not yield any useful information unless the partition is used as a disk image for a VM.)

Comment: `Product: SABRENT` - enough said. 90% of Sabrent USB/SATA adapters are *Hot Garbage™*

Comment: You might try to remove the harddrive from its chassi and plug it directly to a SATA port. With some luck, only the USB controller has a malfunction. Also, when trying to repair broken data, always make a complete backup of the broken data.

Comment: thanks for all the help, I learnt a few things that is the most important. I am saving my SATA drive, and giving up on this for now. Those were just redundant backups, so no loss there. thanks telcoM for the pointers, and advice on posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first assumption would be a faulty case, particularly as you've got pluggable USB involved. Check that it's plugged in properly (both ends of the cable) and there's sufficient power.

I would also check the partition table, which you added to your question. Unfortunately it too shows a faulty read from the device, which is why I suspect the hardware.

Sadly, there are lots of "it doesn't work" posts with the particular vendor id (`0x152d`) and the product id (`0x1561`) that you showed. As an example I searched Google for "[linux sabrent 152d 1561 usb](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+sabrent+152d+1561+usb)". You might be better with a different case (I've found no issues with my RSHTECH 3.5in SATA case, but as they're all built to low budgets my experience suggests it's often a matter of potluck.)

Comment: thanks again for the swift reply, I think you were right from the start. Lesson learnt about cheap connectors between quality devices, an obvious weakest link analogy when you think about it.